# Filter Table Using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, html-table

I also have an AngularJS controller which looks like this:

```
app.controller('StudentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.filter: {
      hobby: {
        football: false,
        tennis: false,
        soccer: false
     }
   }
   $scope.students: [
      {   
         name: John,
         hobby: [soccer, football, tennis]
      },
      {
         name: James,
         hobby: [soccer, tennis]
      }
  ]
]);
```

On the html side, I have some checkboxes and a table displaying table of students:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter.hobby.soccer"><label>Soccer</label>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter.hobby.tennis"><label>Tennis</label>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter.hobby.football"><label>Football</label>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Hobbies</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="student in students">
    <tr ng-hide="rotation.hideRotation">
      <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ student.hobby.join(', ')  }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to know how I can filter the tables using AngularJS. For instance, when I click the checkbox to filter football, only James will show up.

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: I agree with @lealceldeiro + your json is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your json is incorrect, it should be:

```
{    
"students": [
        {   
           "name": "John",
           "hobby": [
              {"sport": "soccer"}, 
              {"sport": "football"}, 
              {"sport": "tennis"}
           ]
        },
        {   
           "name": "James",
           "hobby": [
              {"sport": "soccer"}, 
              {"sport": "tennis"}
           ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and the answer is by having a `angular.ForEach` loop:

```
$scope.selectedStudents = [];
angular.ForEach(studentsArr,function(value,key){
   // looping on each student's hobbies
   angular.ForEach(value.hobby,function(value2,key2){
     if(value2.sport == $scope.searchForSport) { 
       $scope.selectedStudents.push(value)
     }
  })
})
```